# how to display all form error at one place

Tags: forms, symfony, error-handling

I have seen various posts regarding same issue but nothing could become useful for me.

This is my Form

```
<form action="" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }} novalidate>
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    <div class="login_field">
        {{ form_label(form.name) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.name) }}                    
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="login_field">
        {{ form_label(form.status) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.status) }}                    
    </div>                
    <div class="login_field">
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="submit_btn" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Error are not being displayed at all. How can i get out of this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to include `form_errors` for every field ...

```
<div class="login_field">
    {{ form_errors(form.name) }}    
    {{ form_label(form.name) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.name) }}                    
</div>
```

... or just use `form_row` to render all the three of them together ...

```
<div class="login_field">
    {{ form_row(form.name) }}                       
</div>
```

... or let your form errors bubble up to the top using the [error_bubbling](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#error-bubbling) option for your form-fields in your FormType class. This means they will then be rendered through `{{ form_errors(form) }}`.

```
$builder->add('fieldname', 'text', array(
    'error_bubbling' => true,
));
```

quick tip: you can include the submit button in your FormType since symfony 2.3 and don't have to manually render it ([reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/button.html)).

Comment: for error_bubbling, i would have to use form_widget...correct?

Comment: if you put `error_bubbling` on every field (inside your FormType class) the errors will bubble up into the parent form meaning they will appear in `{{ form_errors(form) }}` if you want them all at the top. quote: *if set to true on a normal field, any errors for that field will be attached to the main form, not to the specific field.* otherwise you will have to add `{{ form_errors(form.fieldname) }}` for every field.

Comment: Ok in my example (for form) how can i add error_bubbling for each field? Can you please provide an example?

Comment: added the example to my answer.

Comment: I set error_bubbling but now getting error "The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form"... inface CSRF token is not being generated using above Form tag... what i am missing?

Comment: `{{ form_rest(form) }}` is missing preferably above the submit button :)

Answer (score 2):

To display all the errors at top of form do like below

```
<ul>
    {% for error in form.vars.errors.form.getErrors(true) %}
        <li>{{ error.message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```